# How to normalize a linear combination of spherical harmonics?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, normalization, spherical-harmonics

I know the formula for normalizing individual spherical harmonics, but do not know how to normalize linear combinations of them

Say I have a system

$  \alpha (\theta, \phi) = aY_{l_1}^{m_1} + bY_{l_2}^{m_2} + cY_{l_3}^{m_3}  $

How would I find a, b, and c such that this system is normalized? Is this possible, or am I asking a conceptually wrong question?

Thank you

Comment: Linear algebra: Apply the orthonormality relation $\int_{\theta=0}^\pi\int_{\varphi=0}^{2\pi}Y_\ell^m \, Y_{\ell'}^{m'}{}^* \, d\Omega=\delta_{\ell\ell'}\, \delta_{mm'}$.

Comment: @CosmasZachos - sigh, yes, not enough coffee this afternoon... $a^{2} + b^{2} + c^{2} = 1$

Comment: @JonCuster pour another cup? $a^*a+b^*b+c^*c=1$